# Automating Amazon RDS Snapshot and Restoration using AWS Lambda and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I'm working on setting up an automated process for creating and managing snapshots of my Amazon RDS production database to facilitate testing in a development environment. I plan to use AWS Lambda functions triggered by a cron-like schedule via CloudWatch Events, with the snapshots stored in an S3 bucket.

I'm currently facing challenges in the following areas:

Snapshot Creation:

How can I use AWS Lambda to create snapshots of my Amazon RDS production database and how can i send it to the DEV database?
What are the best practices for handling permissions and security during this snapshot creation process?
Scheduling with CloudWatch Events:

What is the recommended approach for scheduling Lambda functions to run on a specific schedule (e.g., every Sunday) using CloudWatch Events?
Storing and Retrieving Snapshots from S3:

How can I upload and download RDS snapshots to and from an S3 bucket using Lambda?
Are there any specific considerations for security and access control when interacting with S3 in this context?
I appreciate any insights, best practices, or code examples that can help me address these specific challenges. Additionally, if you have any alternative approaches for automating the process of refreshing a development database with production data, I'd be open to suggestions.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: You mention storing snapshots in S3, but AWS RDS snapshots are not stored in S3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html Are you actually planning to use something like `mysqldump` or `pgdump` to create your database "snapshot"? What specific database engine are you running in RDS?

Comment: what i need exactly is to test somethings on my RDS database so what i'm thinking to do is creating a snapshot every week ( cron ) from my prod DB , export it to s3 and then from the s3 i import that snapshot to the dev DB

Comment: Your question is unfocused and your clarification comment doesn't clarify anything, it just restates the very vague details of your question. Can you not even tell us what DB engine you are running? Also, some of the points in your question, like asking for best practices with Lambda scheduling in CloudWatch Events don't make much sense. You schedule Lambdas with CloudWatch Events cron expressions. There is only one way to do that. What would be the "best practice"?

Comment: @YassineMathlouthi you can't copy rds snapshots to s3. rds snapshots never leave rds

Comment: See my answer - I pointed you ihn the correct direction for your use case.

Comment: im using postgresql btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about a very detailed use case (which is why community closed it). However I will point you in the right direction.

This use case can be performed using Lambda and the AWS SDK. For your use case, you need to use:

1. RDS API to perform RDS tasks like creating a snapshot
2. S3 API to perform S3 operation such as uploading snapshot data (ie - its ARN) to a bucket
3. Lambda runtime API to create the Lambda function.

To get started, looked at the RDS Scenario in the [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). The link to the RDS scenario is located at the bottom of this thread. In fact, all AWS SDK logic you need to perform this use case can be found in Code Lib.

The RDS Scenario shows you how to perform various tasks using the RDS API. In fact, you will learn how to perform these tasks:

1. Returns a list of the available DB engines.
2. Selects an engine family and create a custom DB parameter group.
3. Gets the parameter groups.
4. Gets parameters in the group.
5. Modifies the auto_increment_offset parameter.
6. Gets and displays the updated parameters.
7. Gets a list of allowed engine versions.
8. Gets a list of micro instance classes available for the selected engine.
9. Creates an RDS database instance that contains a MySql database and uses the parameter group.
10. Waits for the DB instance to be ready and prints out the connection endpoint value.
11. Creates a snapshot of the DB instance.
12. Waits for an RDS DB snapshot to be ready.
13. Deletes the  RDS DB instance.
14. Deletes the parameter group.

As you can see, you will learn how to create a snapshot in addition to other RDS tasks.

So you can wrap RDS/S3 logic into an AWS Lambda function. As far as scheduling it, use CRON Expressions. This way, your Lambda function will be invoked according to the CRON Expression.

See this use case in Code Lib. As you can see, there are difference programming languagues so you can learn how to do this in Python, Java, C#, etc,

[Get started with Amazon RDS DB instances using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/rds_example_rds_Scenario_GetStartedInstances_section.html)

As noted in the comment - you cannot get binary data that represents the actual snapshot file. What you can do however is store snapshot data like its ARN into S3. Then you can call [copyDBSnapshot](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/rds/model/CopyDbSnapshotRequest.html) when you want to copy it to a target database.

**UPDATE**

I just tested the RDS Scenario using Java RDS API, it works without issue:

[image]

All AWS code examples located in Code Lib been tested many times!